# Error in plotting ROC curve in R - Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "factor"

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, roc

I am working on a program where I train and test using SVM and then where I have to plot an ROC curve. It is producing me an error that I have been trying to solve. Google and Stackoverflow haven't been of much help unfortunately. :(
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
> head(weather.train)
```

[image]

My dataset can found in the link above.

```
library(e1071)
library(ROCR)
library(kernlab)
library(caret)


weather.train<-read.csv("weather.train.csv")
weather.test<-read.csv("weather.test.csv")

head(weather.train)
for(name in names(weather.test)){ # For every column,
  if(is.factor(weather.test[[name]])) {# if it's a factor variable,
    ## change its set of *levels* (possible values)
    ## to that of the training set.
    weather.test[[name]] <- factor(weather.test[[name]],
                                   levels=levels(weather.train[[name]]))
  }}
weather.train$Date <- NULL
weather.test$Date <- NULL

## train a support vector machine
svm_Train<-svm(RainTomorrow ~ .,data=weather.train,kernel = "radial", 
               cost=100,scale=F)

Prediction_Weather<- predict(svm_Train, weather.test)

Init<-table(truth = weather.test$RainTomorrow, prediction = Prediction_Weather)
confusionMatrix(Init)
#Tuning
best.tune(svm,RainTomorrow ~ ., data = weather.train,ranges = list(cost = 10^(-3:3), gamma = 10^(-3:3)))
svm_Train<-svm(RainTomorrow ~ .,data=weather.train,kernel = "radial", 
               cost=100,gamma=0.001,scale=F)
Prediction_Weather_Tuned<- predict(svm_Train, weather.test)
Accuracy<-table(truth = weather.test$RainTomorrow, prediction = Prediction_Weather)
confusionMatrix(Accuracy)
#Error is in the line. This part is for the ROC
svmPredict <- predict(Prediction_Weather_Tuned, weather.test)
pred <- prediction(attr(svmPredict,"probabilities")[,1], weather.test$RainTomorrow)
result <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(result)

plot(svmPerf)
```

> svmPredict <- predict(Prediction_Weather_Tuned, weather.test)

Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: What were you hoping that line would do? It looks like `Prediction_Weather_Tuned` is a vector of predicted classes, what were you hoping to do with those predicted classes?

Comment: Any idea on how do I change it? Any suggestions would help please? This is what I am getting:                                                                      > class(Prediction_Weather_Tuned)
[1] "factor"

Comment: My best guess is that you want to do something like `predict(svm_Train, weather.test, probability = TRUE)` to get predicted probabilities. Otherwise you need to try to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried that and the same error persists.                                          This is my assignment question: The aim of this task is to construct an SVM to predict rain tomorrow (RainTomorrow)from today’s weather conditions. Plot and compare the ROC curves for the default and the tuned classifier on the test set.

Answer (score 0):

`Prediction_Weather_Tuned` is not a trained SVM.

Wrong variable type rethink your code, and make sure you use the right variables. You want to predict using a SVM, not predict using an earlier prediction.